# How to call an .exe (C++) from windows console to create a folder in a different directory (or any directory)?

Tags: c++, winapi, cmd

I have been researching a topic unsuccessfully for a couple of days. I'm a C ++ rookie, and as a practice i decided to **make a basic (very very basic) copy of a version control system**.

**I have separated the project into steps**. The first step (splited in activities) is:

1. The user searches, in the windows console, for the directory where the files he wants to track are located. Let's say he reached the desired path: ***C:\MyProjectFolder\ProjectToTrack>***
2. Once inside ***ProjectToTrack*** folder the user applies this command: ***C:\MyProjectFolder\ProjectToTrack> emi track***. ***"emi"*** is the name of the .EXE that i created in C ++ and the ***track*** parameter tells to the executable to create a hidden folder inside the ***ProjectToTrack*** folder.

   - Note: Obviously ***emi.exe*** is not in the path ***C:\MyProjectFolder\ProjectToTrack***, let's say that ***emi.exe*** is in ***C:\ProgramFiles\emi\emi.exe***

**That's it, once this is done I will pass the second step**, but I will take care of that problem later.

**For now, after practicing and reviewing documentation i have achieved:**

1. The ***.exe*** that creates a hidden folder in the path that was sent to it as a parameter, having said that ...
2. I also know how to send parameters to an ***.exe*** through windows console.

### **But, what I still can't get is:**

1. Calling to ***emi.exe (C:\ProgramFiles\emi\emi.exe)*** through the console from any directory (necessary to track any file in any folder).
2. When ***C:\MyProjectFolder\ProjectToTrack> emi track*** is applied, I know how to send the parameter ***track*** to ***emi.exe***, however, it is evident that I must also capture the current path (path i accessed from the console), so that ***emi.exe*** knows where to create the hidden trace folder; well, i still don't figure out how to capture and send this path to the main function of the .exe.

I have not found something related to what i need, english is not my default language so maybe i'm not using the correct terms, I hope that what i have said here is understandable.

**PS.1.** I'm currently trying to build this project using **"windows.h"**, i would appreciate it if your comments were related to this library. Once i have understood this, I will start practicing with portability.

**PS.2.** I don't want a detailed solution, I just want an opinion or recommendation and maybe some links where to find what I need, I can do the rest.

Thank you!

Comment: If you are coming from Linux, generally creating something in windows that would pass from/to a console application is a bad idea.

Comment: Even a simple VCS is a complicated task for a rookie. I salute your ambition.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis, I understand, but I don't mean that I'll take the same code and try to make it work on another platform, I meant that perhaps I can apply what I have learned to take another paradigm and start a more interesting portable project from scratch.

Comment: @user4581301, Ambitious or stupid, I don't know at this point :), anyway it's an interesting project and the idea for now is to learn.

Comment: When I'm tempted to laugh at people aiming high, I remember this guy back in the early 90's screwing a round with a "just a hobby, won't be big and professional like gnu" OS kernel just for fun/learning. Interesting side note, a while later he got pissed off at the state of version control software and churned out git.

Comment: @user we are not in 90s. The scientific approach might be correct but, in real world, chances that he will be just wasting time are extremely high. I don't discourage his actions but he must be prepared to be a looooong time ‍.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Calling to emi.exe (C:\ProgramFiles\emi\emi.exe) through the console from any directory (necessary to track any file in any folder).

For this you need to add the folder of your executable (i.e. C:\ProgramFiles\emi) to the system global variable called `PATH` (both Windows and Linux work this way, and must be MAC OS as well but I never used it).

> 2. When C:\MyProjectFolder\ProjectToTrack> emi track is applied, I know how to send the parameter track to emi.exe, however, it is evident that I must also capture the current path (path i accessed from the console), so that emi.exe knows where to create the hidden trace folder; well, i still don't figure out how to capture and send this path to the main function of the .exe.

For this take a look at this STD function here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/current_path (personally I've never used it but must be what's you're looking for).

Good luck with your endeavor!

Comment: **A1.** Oh man, I feel so silly, I've added environment variables for different programs these weeks, I don't know why I didn't think about it before. I think that happens when you think about the same thing a lot, an outside look can help.
**A2.** I will definitely check it to see if it applies to what I need.

Well, I'll apply the recommendations, and i'll come back with the result. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Let us know the outcome in any case ;)

Comment: It worked great, I can call emi.exe from any directory (environment variable); And, I was able to capture the route I was on. I still need to add some conditionals to control certain behaviors, but the first step is almost done. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm glad I was helpful, and thanks for accepting my answer. Consider upvoting it as well.

Answer (score 0):

If the user does not pass in a target path explicitly as a parameter, the EXE can use the Win32 [`GetCurrentDirectory()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getcurrentdirectory) function, or in C++17 and later the standard [`std::filesystem::current_path()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/current_path) function, to retrieve its current "working directory".

If the user navigates a console window to `C:\MyProjectFolder\ProjectToTrack` and then executes `C:\ProgramFiles\emi\emi.exe`, the current working directory will initially be `C:\MyProjectFolder\ProjectToTrack`.